How to apply App metrics for gRPC in NET 8
I try to apply metrics to measure anything in gRPC services but It not run well. Anything suggestion for me. I also find on google but I cannot any example about it.
builder.Services.AddOpenTelemetry()
    .WithMetrics(x =>
    {
        x.AddMeter("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel");
        x.AddMeter("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing");
        x.AddMeter("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting");
        x.AddMeter("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics");
        x.AddPrometheusExporter();

    })
    .WithTracing(x =>
    {
        if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            x.SetSampler<AlwaysOnSampler>();
        }

        //x.AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation();
        x.AddGrpcClientInstrumentation();
        //x.AddHttpClientInstrumentation();
    });

// Register all services
builder.Services.RegisterServices(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddGrpc();

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGrpcService<OutrightServices>();

app.MapPrometheusScrapingEndpoint();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

It's a appsettings.json
 "Kestrel": {
   "Endpoints": {
     "grpc": {
       "Url": "localhost:7442",
       "Protocols": "Http2"
     }
   }
 },

But I cannot run "localhost:7442/metrics"
I don't know any mistakes in my code. Please help
Many thanks

I'm not a .NET developer. Your question is not a minimal repro of your issue that anyone could run to see the error for themselves. You say "it did not run well" but you don't provide the output in your question nor the errors that arise. I Googled gRPC OpenTelemetry and .NET and found Experimental Support for gRPC requests which includes an example that may help you.
